# Know if a date is from today in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, date

I've got a **date** field.

**For example :**

```
01/03/2016 09:40:35
```

I would like to know if this date is from **Today**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`01/03/2016 09:40:35` is not a date, it is displayed in a format you want to see. It will be a date if you convert it using **TO_DATE**.

To know if the date part is current date, you need to compare it with **SYSDATE**.

For example,

```
SQL> SELECT
  2    CASE
  3      WHEN TRUNC(to_date('01/03/2016 09:40:35', 'dd/mm/yyyy hh24:mi:ss')) = TRUNC(SYSDATE)
  4      THEN 'Today'
  5      ELSE 'Not Today'
  6    END date_check
  7  FROM dual;

DATE_CHECK
----------
Today

SQL>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can compare your date value with `TRUNC(SYSDATE)` or `TRUNC(SYSTIMESTAMP)`, for example.

Answer (score 1):

This will work for your requirements

```
select 
case when to_char(yourdatefield,'dd/mm/yyyy hh24:mi:ss')= to_char(sysdate,'dd/mm/yyyy hh24:mi:ss') 
then 'today'
else 'not today'
end
from dual;
```